# Set focus on Guake when opening it

Tags: window, focus, ubuntu-14.04

Appologies if this was asked before -- I couldn't find any similar questions.

I'm using Guake! 0.4.4 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My hotkey to open and close the terminal it is set to F12.

When I open the terminal, I would like to have focus on the window so that I can immediately type on the commandline. However, I have to manually activate the window first, either by Alt+Tab'ing to it or by clicking the terminal.

How do I set it up so that whenever I hit F12 to open Guake, I immediately activate/focus on its window and can start typing on the commandline?

P.S.: I wanted to add the tag "Guake" to this, but lack the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just resolved this problem myself. For me, the problem was caused by Focus Prevention. I solved the problem by changing the Focus Prevention behavior using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run it
3. Click General Options
4. Click the Focus & Raise Behavior tab
5. Add `& !(name=guake)` to the Focus Prevention Windows box. If there was nothing in that box, leave off the `&`.

You can also fix it by simply setting the Focus Prevention Level to `off` but that will affect focus prevention for all windows.

Comment: Thank you!

It appeared to be Focus Prevention for me, as well. However, adding `& !(name=guake)` to the Focus Prevention Window box didn't help. I had to turn off Focus Prevention entirely.

Comment: The greatest thanks, you've solved the problem that made me extremely nervous up until now!